# Rota c# redirecionando para action errada

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc, route

Tenho uma action que retorna uma PartialView

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF(int idUF)
{
   //It do something and returns a PartialView
}
```

Essa action está mapeada da seguinte forma:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "SelecionarCidades",
     url: "SelecionarCidades/{idUF}", 
     defaults: new { controller = "Regioes", action = "SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF" }
);
```

Por fim tenho faço uma requisição AJAX à esta action:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/Regioes/SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF',
   data: { 'idUF': idUF },
   dataType: 'html',
   cache: false,

   beforeSend: function (data) {
   },

   success: function (data) {
        //do something
   },

   error: function (data) {
       //do something
   }
});
```

O problema que tenho é que esta requisição ajax não encontra esta action `SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF`, e sim a action `Index`, ou seja, ele vai pra action errada. Alguém que já passou por isso poderia me ajudar:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Teste",
                url: "SelecionarCidades/{idUF}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Regioes", action = "SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF", idUF = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Verifique a ordem em que foi colocada a regra. Ela tem que vir antes da rota default, senão não irá funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema esteja na url da sua rota. Você colocou "SelecionarCidades" e não "SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF" que é o nome correto da Action e o nome que você chama no Ajax.

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "SelecionarCidades",
 url: "SelecionarCidades/{idUF}", 
 defaults: new { controller = "Regioes", action ="SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF",idUF = UrlParameter.Optional  }
);
```

A rota correta seria:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 name: "SelecionarCidades",
 url: "SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF/{idUF}", 
 defaults: new { controller = "Regioes", action ="SelectCidadesPorCodigoUF",idUF = UrlParameter.Optional  }
);
```